# iOS stream song from url with http header

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, http-headers, audio-streaming

I have a server that has songs on it. I would like to stream from this server to my iphone and I realize I can do this with `AVPlayer` and `initWithUrl`.  However, the catch is that the URL requires an authentication header.  Is there any way to send an http header with a song to stream it?

If not, does anyone know of any workarounds?

Thanks.

Comment: any updates on this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do what danh said - use a NSMutableURLRequest to pass the auth data, and NSURLConnection to write the audio data to a file.  You can check how much data you've downloaded in didReceiveData:.  Once the file is "big enough" (you'll have to decide what that means), you can play it using AVAudioPlayer's initWithContentsOfURL (pass the file URL there).  I've got an app on the store using this technique and it works fine.  One piece of advice, some files will cause AVAudioPlayer to return a bizarre error ([error code] == 2003334207).  If you get that, wait until the file downloads completely, then it will play.

Comment: Not really, I wouldn't use this approach any more to be honest. Audio Queue Services are harder to deal with but more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

[NSMutableURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) let's you set header's using a dictionary-like interface.  See `setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:`.   You can use that to make the request yourself, save the file to a a file URL using NSData `writeToFile:atomically:`.  Then send the file url to the AVPlayer.

Comment: Will this not wait for the entire file to be downloaded before playing it?  I need the song to be played while it is being downloaded.

Comment: Did you find the answer for this?